# angular2/ionic2 Auto retrieve verification code or OTP

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a mobile number field and OTP field. Once user enters the mobile number, i am getting the OTP message.
How do i get the OTP number and auto populate the number on OTP textbox.

Is it possible(any plugin available) using Angular 2 / ionic 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [cordova-plugin-sms](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms) to intercept SMS messages, and read the OTP to put on your textbox